# Showing that if n is a natural number larger than 3, then $n!>2^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Showing that if n is a natural number larger than $3$, then $n! > 2^n$.

My try:

Base Case:

If $n=4$, then $4!>2^4$

$24>16$

So, the base case is true.

Assuming $P(k)$ is true.

$k!>2^k$

Now we need to show that $P(k+1)$ is true.

$(k+1)!=2^{k+1}$

Proof:

$(k+1)!>(k+1)k!$

$\implies (k+1)2^k$

After this I have no idea how to solve further.

Can anyone explain how to continue.

Comment: Why do you write $(k+1)!=2^{k+1}$?  that clearly isn't true.

Comment: @lulu I edited it should be $>$, thanks

Answer (score 2):

After finding out that the base case is true and assuming $P(k)$ is true, for $P(k+1)$ we have

$$(k+1)! = (k+1)k! > (k+1)2^k$$

by inductive argument and since $k+1 > 2$ we have $(k+1)! > 2^{k+1}$.

Comment: Language quibble: You don't assume $P(k)$ is true for *all* $k$, you merely assume that $P(k)$ is true (and then proceed to prove that $P(k+1)$ is also true).

Comment: Yes, that's right. "$P(k)$ is true for all $k$" is what we should have concluded in the end. Thank you for the warning :)

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
for any $m > 0$,
if $n \ge em$ then
$n! > m^n$.

Proof:

Start with $n! > (n/e)^n$.
This can be proved by induction
from
$(1+1/n)^n < e$;
this, in turn,
has been shown here
many times.

If $n \ge em$
then
$n! > (n/e)^n
\ge (em/e)^n
=m^n$.

For your case
with $m=2$,
if
$n \ge em
\approx 5.4...$
or
$n \ge 6$,
$n! > 2^n$.

The remaining cases can be checked by hand.

You can also show,
using
$n! < (n/2)^n$
for $n \ge 6$,
that
if $m \ge 6$
and $n \le 2m$
then
$n! < m^n$.

Therefore,
if
$r(n) = \dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}$,
then
$\dfrac1{e}
\lt r(n)
\lt \dfrac1{2}
$
for
$n \ge 6$.